# SO as a place for teaching or tutorials?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should SO host howto-style writeups after all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104473/should-so-host-howto-style-writeups-after-all)

We have a lot of great Q and A, but what if we aggregated these questions to a place on the site where we host tutorials on a subject?

Ideally, we could replace existing bad-knowledge sites that are static and not community-driven.

For an example, we have *many* questions on SQL injection (just an example, not a fact). Some are amazing, some are okay, some are awful, and lots are perhaps not the same question but exist because of the same flawed understanding of the subject.

We could create a sister-site, or something in that vein, where people don't post questions, but rather request tutorials on a subject, which refrences questions asked here on the site.

This would bring value in the form of finding out what people want to learn, and express more complete knowledge for people who want to learn something. It's like Q and A, except we're finding topics not specifics.

Does anyone else like this idea? In theory we could accomplish this as a third-party via the data-api as well if it's not in the scope of SE.

Comment: I like it. I've thought about this before as well, to extend even further all of the knowledge aggregated on SE sites. Think about it, right now THE place to go for help is SE, where you get some great answers, and some not-so-great answers. If we could now take this data, with its contributors, and create an ultimate repository (for separate subjects) where questions and answers are transformed into a professional, tutorial style write up, this would be great. No more searching for horribly formatted tutorials on the web. As a student, and a developer, this would be awesome for SO and others.

Comment: Propose it over on http://area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is an old idea.  You need an *expert* to want to take the time on your site and post the tutorial.  Why your site and not his blog?  Don't attempt this until you have a 95% case for "my site".