# New content type: tutorial

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow a central store for tutorials?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134645/is-stack-overflow-a-central-store-for-tutorials)

Posting your own tutorials and in that post link to the tutorial on your own website? I know we can 'answer our own question', but a more extended version of this would be a full-blown tutorial.

Next to the 'Ask a question' we could have a button 'Make tutorial' which disables the answer section and gives more focus to the comment section. Also the input field (WYSIWYG editor) could be a bit more modified (Headings for example!) for the author of the tutorial. I think that this is great. Why? Loads of questions are basically the same (especially CSS or jQuery related in my experience) and if some people put some effort in writing a to-the-point and crystal clear tutorial (I would try to be one of them) we could really save people some time.

It's just an idea though. I don't know in how far this can be applied.

Comment: Tutorials as self-answers were brought up just a few days ago... [Is Stack Overflow a central store for tutorials?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134645/is-stack-overflow-a-central-store-for-tutorials)

Answer (score 9):

Tutorials are neither questions nor answers. If a question needs a full-blown tutorial to answer, it is likely too broad and therefore "not a real question" or "not constructive". Your proposal of creating a format that *greatly detracts* from Q&A doesn't sit too well with Stack Exchange, whose very building blocks are *questions* and *answers*.

If something needs a canonical answer in our site, it should be an answer to a question, not a tutorial.