# Is there any place to put my own how to?

Tags: discussion, questions, tutorials

I have found a way to do something (safely remove of OAuth of .NET MVC4 application) on my own. I've searched a lot on the internet about this and can't find how to.

**There's any place here that I can put the step by step on Stack Overflow?**

**-- EDIT --**

Thanks for all replies and sorry for not seeing similar questions before asking.
Later I'll put the step by step in Answer/Question format on the SO, I think this will help a lot of people.

Comment: See also: [Is posting a tutorial for compiling a specific software okay?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188919)

Comment: Perfectly fine, just ask the question you were asking yourself originally, and then answer it with the step-by-step procedure. Remember, you're encouraged to answer your own questions

Comment: Also see: [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Stack Overflow is not a **tutorial site** it's a [Q&A type of site](https://stackexchange.com/about). You can consult the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what types of posts are accepted here.

Now if you rule out the tutorial idea, you can ask a question about `.NET MVC4` and answer it yourself if you judge it could help someone. Then again, make sure you consult the help center to make sure your question fits the Q&A format so it gets positive feedback.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ask a question on SO, then at the bottom there is an "Answer your Question" button

Comment: Just make sure that the question and answer each stand on their own and that they are both of sufficient standard.